# In laravel 5.4 how can i get only the users friends posts?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

```
$user_id = auth::user()->id;
$user_friends = User::find($user_id)->friends;
$user_friends_id = $user_friends->pluck('id');
$posts = Post::where('user_id', $user_friends_id)->get();
return view('dashboard')->with('posts', $posts);
```

So far i've got the users friends id's in $user_friends_id and then matching them to the user id on the posts but its only getting the first friends posts and not the rest. How can i change it to get all the friends posts and not just the first friends?

Comment: try using `$posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $user_friends_id)`

Comment: You should try a join. (relationships) Using multiple queries can get slow really fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to execute an additional query with `find()` and then get all friends objects just to get their IDs. It's a huge overhead. Just do this:

```
Post::whereIn('user_id', auth()->user()->friends()->pluck('id'))->get()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-wherein):

```
$user_id = auth::user()->id;
$user_friends = User::find($user_id)->friends;
$user_friends_id = $user_friends->pluck('id');
$posts = Post::whereIN('user_id', $user_friends_id)->get();
return view('dashboard')->with('posts', $posts);
```

In one line:

```
$posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', auth()->user()->friends()->pluck('id'))->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses), for which you need an array of IDs. The [Pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-collections#available-methods) function gives you a collection of just a specific column (key), so you need to call `toArray` on it to have an array with the values instead of a collection.
Further, you can eliminate the extra query with `User::find` since you are looking for the authenticated user and you already have queried that with `Auth::user()`.

So I would say you need the following:

```
$user_friends = Auth::user()->friends;
$user_friends_id = $user_friends->pluck('id')->toArray();
$posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $user_friends_id)->get();
return view('dashboard')->with('posts', $posts);
```

Comment: You don't need to use the `toArray()` method because `whereIn()` works with collection too.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Oh nice, I didn't know that. Thank you!